# Visual Studio Code DDEV and auto reload on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ddev

I'm using DDEV with Visual Studio Code and I tried to configure Live Server Extension to automatically auto reload page that I'm working on in Chrome when I hit save in VSC, but it doesn't seem to work with PHP.

Is there a way to configure this to work with DDEV?

I can't seam to find any info on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it another way, with guard and guard-liveguard on linux.

The workflow was:

[guard](https://github.com/guard/guard#readme) installation

[guard-livereload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) installation

Installation was not quite straightforward, but you can follow the instructions in Terminal and install what's missing if it tells you so.

Guard placed Guardfile inside of /home/user directory so I edited it to contain only this, regarding livereload pard:

```
guard 'livereload' do
watch(%r{.+\.(css|scss|html|php|js)$})
end
```

Then I installed Liveguard Google Chrome Browser Extension from here:
http://livereload.com/extensions/

Under settings I had to enable "Allow access to file URLs".

Also, you have to press liveguard extension icon in Chrome in order for it to track changes.

That's about it, now when I edit any of the file types entered in Guardfile (you can edit and add what you need, of course) it automatically reloads my Chrome window whit the edited page opened.